# TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Not rolling logs in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, logback

logback TimeBasedRollingPolicy not seems to be working with below configuration.

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true"
        scanPeriod="30 seconds">
        <property name="LOG_PATH" value="logs" />
        <property name="LOG_ARCHIVE" value="${LOG_PATH}/bkp" />
        <springProperty scope="context" name="appName" source="spring.application.name"/>
        <timestamp key="timestamp-by-second"
                datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss" />
        <appender name="Console-Appender"
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
                <layout>
                        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="Spring-logAppender"
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <file>${LOG_PATH}/Spring.log</file>
                <rollingPolicy
                        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE}/Spring.log%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
                        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                        <totalSizeCap>50MB</totalSizeCap>
                </rollingPolicy>
                <encoder>
                        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [${appName},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}] [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
        </appender>
        <appender name="Database-logAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <file>${LOG_PATH}/Database.log</file>
                <rollingPolicy
                        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE}/Database.log%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
                        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                        <totalSizeCap>50MB</totalSizeCap>
                </rollingPolicy>
                <encoder>
                        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [${appName},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}] [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
        </appender>

        <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="trace"
                additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="Spring-logAppender" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="error"
                additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="Database-logAppender" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="error"
                additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="Database-Appender" />
        </logger>
        <root level="debug">
                <appender-ref ref="Spring-Appender" />
        </root>
</configuration>
```

is there any fault in this? am using Spring: 2.1.1.RELEASE. none of the logs are rolling or backed up on the next day. how do i check if any errors in this log configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use for logging, try this, Hope this helps.

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="path">C:/pathyouwant/</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
                >
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="App-Appender" fileName="${path}/app.log" 
                     filePattern="${path}/zuul_app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <File name="SpringBoot-Appender" fileName="${path}/app_springboot.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
         <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="trace"
                additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="Spring-logAppender" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="error"
                additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="Database-logAppender" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="error"
                additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="Database-Appender" />
        </logger>
        <Root>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```